# How does fire on sidewalk spaces affect vehicles (outside of the building)

Tags: flash-point

When fire spreads to spaces outside of the building, how does this affect vehicle movements and usage?

- Do vehicles extinguish fire as they drive over it?
- Are vehicles unable to drive through fires (until they are extinguished). Pretty tough mechanism if so.
- Do vehicles simply ignore the fire but firefighters on foot do not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fires spread outdoors and affect firemen/victims accordingly, but are removed at the end of the Advance Fire phase, so they shouldn't have any impact on vehicle movement.